# AWS EC2 - Get EBS Volume information

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way/method in the EC2/AWS API such that I can get the EBS volume that is attached to a particular EC2 instance?

IE:
I just want something that allows me to do something along the lines of:
method(instance_id) - returns the EBS volume that this particular instance_id is attached to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) command from the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).

An example:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?InstanceId==`i-058aba2af1c14e93e`].BlockDeviceMappings[*]'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know your instance ID, you can use CLI command:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=i-08e0325f9e7218a02
```

where `Values` is my instance ID.

The answer looks like:

```
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2023-02-28T23:44:46+00:00",
                    "Device": "/dev/xvda",
                    "InstanceId": "i-08e0325f9e7218a02",
                    "State": "attached",
                    "VolumeId": "vol-087d2d787f60de5d8",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true
                }
            ],
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b",
            "CreateTime": "2023-02-28T23:44:46.880000+00:00",
            "Encrypted": false,
            "Size": 8,
            "SnapshotId": "snap-0d521a3c01cf13eee",
            "State": "in-use",
            "VolumeId": "vol-087d2d787f60de5d8",
            "Iops": 100,
            "VolumeType": "gp2",
            "MultiAttachEnabled": false
        }
    ]
}
```